# returning varchar(MAX) from a function returns truncated string

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am having a strange problem. I have a function which returns a large string by concatenating several other strings.

In some cases the string is too long and is getting truncated.

For example, there is an instance when a string of length 379999 is supposed to be returned, but what I see is that the string is truncated and the length is only 65536.

I am sure that varchar(MAX) can hold a string greater that 65536, but where am I going wrong here? The function has been shown below.

[UPDATE]

this function is being used in several stored procedures, and the stored procedures are used by the crystal reports to display data.

[UPDATE END]

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetShipContSernText](
@shipContNum numeric(9)) returns Varchar(MAX) begin

declare serns cursor for


select
    serial_number
from
    serial_number_view
where
    ship_cont_num = @shipContNum
    and
    template_id is null

open serns;

declare @text varchar(MAX);
declare @serialNumber nvarchar(50);

fetch next from serns into @serialNumber;

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    -- cannot concat a null string.

    if (@text is null)
             set @text = @serialNumber; 
    else
          set @text = @text + N', ' + @serialNumber;
    end 
    fetch next from serns into @serialNumber;
end;

close serns;
deallocate serns;

return @text;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function is indeed returning a sting more than 65536 characters, i used the LEN function and found the length to be much greater. It was the grid which was restricting the length. Now i need to find why is the crystal report truncating the string.
Bunch of thanks to Jonas :)

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you can't return the rows and concatenate in the code?

You are mixing varchar and nvarchar.

Also you need to use [SQL Native Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131035.aspx) to be able to use varchar(max) as a return value.

Comment: i cannot do concatenation in code as the stored proc feeds a crystal report.

the db i am using is sql server 2005, and i am assuming that the crystal reports too use sql native client to fetch the data, please correct me if i am wrong.

If i execute the function in sql management studio i still get a string of length 65536.

Comment: Strange because I just tried your code and got a length of more than 400000 in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: wooow!! I tried again and again but i still get only a string of length 65536. 
I tried to get the "results to text", surprisingly i see the string much shorter.

I am wondering how is it that it is working for you. Are there any settings which are restricting the length.

Comment: SSMS has a setting in tools>options>query results>results to text.  It doesn't really go any higher than 65536.  you cna try exporting data via another method is my best choice.  Try exporting directly to a text file.

Comment: Is it select len(@text) that reports 65536 for you?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Crystal Reports which makes it interpret varchar(max) fields as varchar(255)

see here: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=5843&PID=17503

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this in my report with `try_cast(<field> as text)` for Crystal Reports 2016 OEM, I think that this would work for other versions as well. So long as they continue to support the text data type.

Crystal Server OEM Embedded 2016
Crystal Reports 2016 Service Pack 9 (developer)
SQL Server 2109